# Long Running Script - jQuery (In IE)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm having an issue with an error keep appearing in IE when using the below jQuery. The error is **'Example page is not responding due to a long running script'**

The script is basically checking google ad slots and whether or not the viewer has an adblock installed, and also whether or not the screen is at 'X' size via display none in CSS.

If you view http://www.prewheeled.co.uk in Chrome on a desktop/laptop, you should see the ad top right. (Please don't click it!)
Now...If you drag edge of the browser window to make it smaller, you should see the ad replaced with a smaller/mobile friendly version.

But rather than have BOTH ads loaded in HTML at all times (View the source to see the two divs holding the ads) I want to only load one of them within the HTML depending on screen size VIA the CSS. Not just hide it via css.

I'm not really familiar with jQuery, I just botched this script together, but IE is driving me mad as per usual...The source jQuery I'm using is: ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

If anybody can help by at least correcting the code for me that would be great, thanks. This is what I've tried, but gives the error in IE11.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(checkAds, 1000);checkAds2();checkAds3();
});
function checkAds() {
    if ($(".google-468").height() == '0') {
            $(".google-468").replaceWith('<div id="block-468"></div><div id="block-responsive-468">Ad Blocker? Our site will not work correctly for you sadly!<br />Please add our site to your allowed list</div>');
    }
}
function checkAds2() {
    if ($("#google-468").css('display') == 'none') {
            $("#google-468").replaceWith('');
    }
}
function checkAds3() {
    if ($("#google-468-responsive").css('display') == 'none') {
            $("#google-468-responsive").replaceWith('');
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, as it's said in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) passing a code to `setTimeout` is strongly discouraged:

> *code*: in the alternate syntax is a string of code you want to execute after delay milliseconds (using this syntax is not recommended for the same reasons as using eval())

So I would recommend calling functions using following syntax:

```
setTimeout(checkAds, 25);
```

But, if you still want to use it like you do, you need to define these functions in `window` context, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/613n7xwp/):

```
window.checkAds = function() {
...
}
```

It wasn't working because when interpreter dynamically wrapped your code in anonymous function, your functions were be undefined in new context.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm wasn't even sure the code was the proper syntax in the first place, like I say I really don't understand jquery at all. But after using your tip and also jshint.com, I have now come up with the following (See my edit in first post) Can you confirm that this is the proper formatting etc? And that it should work in IE?

Comment: Yes, this seems ok in general, but use `html()` instead of `replaceWith()`. BTW, if my tip was useful, you can upvote it.

Comment: Argh. I'm still getting the 'Long running script' error in IE11. :-( Also my #google-468-responsive DIV doesn't seem to show the ads on a small screen anymore. I just don't know what's wrong? PS:I tried to upvote but need more reputation or something. Thumbs up to you for helping me.

Comment: At least try to narrow down the script that is causing this error. What this line should do `$(".google-468").height() == '0'`?

Comment: That line should replace the google div (#google-468) with <div id="block-468"></div><div id="block-responsive-468">Ad Blocker? Our site will not work correctly for you sadly!<br />Please add our site to your allowed list</div>...............Using the .html shows both of my google divs (#google-468) AND (#google-468-responsive) in the HTML, but I'm trying to remove the one that's not active at the time of 'X' screen size.

Comment: May be best if I can show you what I'm trying to do, apologies for the 'skittish' replies, I'm not really experienced in coding like this. If you view http://www.prewheeled.co.uk in Chrome on a desktop/laptop, you should see the ad top right. (Please don't click it!) Now...If you drag edge of the browser window to make it smaller, you should see the ad replaced with a smaller/mobile friendly version. But rather than have BOTH ads loaded in HTML at all times, I want to only load one of them within the HTML depending on screen size VIA the CSS. Not just hide it via css.

Comment: Sorry...Additionally, there's the checking of whether or not the viewer has an adblock enabled! If you do, then you can try the screen resizing with that as well to see how the adblock image is replaced with another div. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I guess you should include this info in your question so others would see. Perhaps it's actually more than one question here or you should do some investigation so you would have a clear problem that needs a clear solution. Now you're asking me (and others) to debug your code and see what's wrong, but this is your part I can't help you, sorry mate.

Comment: :-( Well all I can do is ask for help...I can't debug code as I don't understand the code. I suppose I'll have to resign myself to just loading all of the ads all of the time and hide them from view with css like I currently have. Unless If I ask a new question about how to achieve what I need, would people be forthcoming with help? In fact I'll edit my question to see what people think.